# Can an id of an html be related even between different html documents that are referenced to each other?

Tags: javascript, html, function

This is a really hard question to explain.

For example, if I have a function "randomFunction" in a JavaScript file "somefile.js," and in another html I have a button that activates function "randomFunction," that has "somefile.js as it's script, will those two "randomFunction"s cooperate with each other?

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: Actually it doesn't make sense. At least to me. Can you post some code?

Comment: Where is the second `randomFunction`? It seems you are only referring to one `randomFunction` in your `somefile.js`

Comment: Define cooperate .. ??

Comment: Make it more clear, I think you can.

Comment: The way I see it, there's only one "randomFunction" function here: the one in "somefile.js". Or?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

There is only a single execution environment per page for JavaScript.

Anything placed into the global scope by one script can be access by any other script script on the page.

Comment: This is completely true in case if script written in same html doc or imported inside same html doc.How could it be possible to  'cooperate' if its not on same page?

Comment: @captain — Since the question only mentions one HTML file, one JS file and states that the JS file is a script on that HTML file … that doesn't matter since it isn't what the question is about.